Alpinejs errors when used in Django templates
I have AlpineJS loaded in my Django base.html template, and throughout the app I'm using AlpineJS in my partials. This works locally, but when I deploy I see errors such as:
Alpine Expression Error: app is not defined
Expression: "app"

This is in the <head> of my Django base.html template:
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

And right above the closing </body> tag:
<script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>

And in the main.js file:
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  Alpine.data('app', () => ({
    modalOpen: false,
    mobileNavOpen: false,
    toggleModal() {
      this.modalOpen = !this.modalOpen
      document.body.classList.toggle('overflow-hidden')
    },
    toggleMobileNav() {
      this.mobileNavOpen = !this.mobileNavOpen
    },
  }))
})

And on my <body> tag:
  <body class="front bg-slate-50" x-data="app">

I'm guessing I need a way to check for AlpineJS before the x-data is applied.

Have you checked whether main.js is actually loaded by the browser in the 'remote' version?

@TUPKAP Good point - I had checked for 404 errors, but apparently there was a MIME type error that I hadn't noticed. Thank you for the pointer!
